# How do I implement a wait_for function into my command?

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to make a bot that will pick a word from a text file and then scramble it and then the user unscrambles the word and types it. But I do not know how to implement the wait_for function into the command.

```
@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Time for chaos')
    Unscrambled_word = random.choice(list(open('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Discord Bots\\Fake Speedjar\\words.txt')))
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading the documentation [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for)

It comes with a good simple example.

There is another library called dpytools that has a helper (wait_for_author) for this kind of simple cases you can check it [here](https://dpytools.readthedocs.io/en/master/waiters.html#dpytools.waiters.wait_for_author)

Basically the wait_for method will wait for something and then return it to you. In this case a "message".

```py
def check(msg):
    return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel

message = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
```

The check function takes only the awaited object(s) and returns a bool indicating if the message Is what you're expecting.

Please check the documentation for further information.